# Running Jython script from terminal with parameter

Tags: python, jython, imagej

I want to invoke Jython scripts from command line, p.e.
`$ /Applications/Fiji.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageJ-macosx --headless little_jython_script.py`

I know about Python's (and therefore Jython's) capability to take parameters by

```
import sys
params = sys.argv[1:]
```

and then calling the script with something like
`$ /Applications/Fiji.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageJ-macosx --headless jython_script_with_params.py param1 param2 param3`.

However, according to to the ImageJ webpage http://imagej.net/Script_parameters it is also possible to code the use of parameters in Jython similar to the Greeting.py example from that website

```
# @String name

# A Jython script with parameters.
# It is the duty of the scripting framework to harvest
# the 'name' parameter from the user, and then display
# the 'greeting' output parameter, based on its type.

print "Hello, " + name + "!"
```

The questions is: How do I specify the parameter `name` in a command line call `$/Applications/Fiji.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageJ-macosx --headless Helloworld.py` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way parameters are available depends on the calling command, where the difference is the additional flags `--ij2` and `--run` in the Jython way. Either `sys.argv` or `# @String` etc. work, but not both at the same time

**1. The classical Python way with sys.argv**

`$/Applications/Fiji.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageJ-macosx --headless JythonScript.py param1 param2`

harvests the parameters for `JythonScript.py` in the classical python way with `sys.argv` , i.e.

```
# @String param1     ### Does NOT work

import sys
program_name = sys.argv[0]
paramvalue1  = sys.argv[1]
paramvalue2  = sys.argv[2]
```

**2. The Jython specific way with # @String etc.**

`$/Applications/Fiji.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageJ-macosx --ij2 --headless --run JythonScript_2.py 'param1=value, param2=value'`

takes parameters in the Jython way

```
# @String param1     
# @Long param2

### See http://imagej.net/Script_parameters#Parameter_types 
### for a complete list of parameter types

import sys
check = sys.argv   
#here check is a length 1 list containing en empty string: check ==['']
```

Note the quotes around the two comma-separated `param=value` pairs. Both single and double quotes work. They can be omitted when only 1 parameter is present. For string parameters make sure to enclose them into the other kind of quotes, or omit the quotes when the string is purely alphanumeric like 
`$/Applications/Fiji.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageJ-macosx --ij2 --headless --run JythonScript_3.py 'stringparam1="string with ',' and space ", stringparam2=abc123'`